# Export custom words and voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking on a regular basis

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturallyspeaking

I am looking for a program than can export custom words and voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking. It should be:

- compatible with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional and Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.
- able to export custom words and voice commands every X hours or days (it's okay if I have to use the Windows Task Scheduler).

If possible:

- free
- can limit the number of the exports (e.g. automatically erase the exports that are one week old)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no program that can do it automatically, but you could write a script for all of that.

Your **commands** are all stored in a file in your user profile folder. The file is `C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\Users\<Your profile's name>\current\MyCmds.dat`. Write a script that copies that file to a different folder. Have the script add a time stamp. Run the script with Task Scheduler.

Your **user defined words** are not stored as conveniently. They can be manually exported with a Dragon macro (since you have Pro), though. A file with your user defined words would be stored in that folder. Add a time stamp to the file in the macro.

Write another script that cleans up these two folders (or run [Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self-cleaning-pc)). Run through Task Scheduler.

**Alternative**

There is a Dragon add-on that will display all new words and commands at the end of the session: **dns.comfort**, available from http://sonic-labs.net/en/products.html. (Disclosure: I am a reseller of this product, though I get no benefit for this recommendation.) This allows you to keep track of the words added.